# Adding link local address

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, ipv6, link-local

If the IPv6 link-local address is manually deleted on an interface, is there a way to obtain the link-local address back without bringing the interface down? The requirement stems from the need to hold onto (IPv4) existing connections on the interface, but also obtain the link-local address on it.

Comment: What operating system? I tested on Linux, and deleting the link-local address and readding it "just works".

Comment: On Linux. I couldn't quite understand you, could you elaborate on the steps?

Comment: Steps are already elaborated by [sleinen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1187852/sleinen). Note that it's nothing more than the same command you would use normally to add an address to the interface!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

GNU/Linux systems typically use "ip" (from the "iproute" package) to configure addresses.  A link-local address would be added using something like

```
ip address add dev eth4 scope link fe80::21b:21ff:febb:5db0/64
```

Did you try that?

If your problem is that you don't know what exact address you should use as the link-local address: These addresses are typically derived from the hardware (MAC) address of the interface.

Take the MAC address of the interface (the "link/ether" field in the result of "ip link show dev ..."), and convert it to Modified EUI-64 according to [this procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Modified_EUI-64).

Then add "fe80::" (standard link-local prefix) to the left and "/64" (as the subnet prefix length) to the right.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take this approach for now.

Comment: You can automatically derive the link local address with `$ ipv6calc --in prefix+mac fe80:: $MACADDR`

Comment: Or just set it to fe80::1?